# ffmpeg overlay issue with rotation

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to execute a command using `ffmpeg` so it performs three tasks for me at once:

1. croping the video (OK)
2. rotate the video for 90° (OK) and
3. add an overlay

Unfortunately, the tasks 1 and 2 are performed, but the overlay isn't. Please help me.. Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i " + path + " -i /storage/emulated/0/image.png -filter_complex [0]crop=" + cut + ":" + cut + ":0:0 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 -c:a [a];[a][1]overlay=10:10 -preset ultrafast -codec:a copy /storage/emulated/0/Nitin/" + videoFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the options `-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90`, you were settings the rotate matrix in your video stream.

It seems your filters are not chained in your filter graph. You could achieve all your goals in a filter chain.

```
[in] ---> crop ---> transpose ---> overlay ---> [out]
                                 ^
                                 |
     ---> movie -----------------|
```

The filter graph showed above can be specified with `-vf` option like below.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=200:200:12:34,transpose=1 [ct];movie=/path/to/the/overlay/image.png [movie];[ct] [movie]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

You should change `crop` parameters to yours, the `transpose` filter with `1` parameter will rotate clock wise by 90 degree, see [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose) for more information.

Also change the movie filter parameter to the path of your image.

At last, these two outputs will centred overlay to generate final output.